# ltrim class name on autoload

Tags: php

I see different library's (in this case Symfony) phpunit bootstrap.php code usually include something like:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    if (0 === strpos(ltrim($class, '/'), 'Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher')) {
        if (file_exists($file = __DIR__.'/../'.substr(str_replace('\\', '/', $class), strlen('Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher')).'.php')) {
            require_once $file;
        }
    }
});
```

I'm wondering in what case will the class name have a leading forward slash?

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on Symfony, but it looks like they are taking a file name and tries to load it, if it has the namespace **Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher**. The **ltrim()** simply removes any residue so that no errors will occur when they add their own search path.

I can only guess, but I am pretty sure that is what's going on.